# CakePHP SaveMany not saving

Tags: cakephp

I have a issue with the SaveMany call in my CakePHP function.

The code below is my current attempt. This now sort of works, it does not make any errors at all but only the savefield will save any data, the saveMany, although it does not come back with errors does NOT save the data?

Please Help???

```
             $InvoiceArrayData = array(
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('workdes' => $WorkHolder)),
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('price' => $PriceHolder)),
            );


            foreach($InvoiceArrayData as $InvoiceArrayKey => $InvoiceArrayValue) {
                debug($InvoiceArrayValue); 
                $this->Invoicedata->saveMany($InvoiceArrayValue['Invoicedata']);

                $this->Invoicedata->saveField('invoicejoblists_id', $MyJobIDInput);

                $this->Invoicedata->saveField('invoicejoblists_id', $MyJobIDInput);
                $this->Session->setFlash('Invoice Data Saved', 'default', array(), 'good');
                //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('/AdminInvoiceSystem/'));
            }
```

When the code runs it does redirect with the saved meessaged but when the database is checked, only the invoicejoblist_id is saved.

Have not not done something right?

Glenn

UPDATE ::

Ok so what I am trying to do is to build an invoice system, I have a number of tables one of which 'invoicedatas' which has 'id, workdes, price, invoicejoblists_id' contained within it. ID is the key and is sent to auto count.

When the user starts to make a new invoice they fill in a form which saves in the other tables. But also in this form they input a work detail and price for that work.

This is then sent over to the function I am working on now, which returns no errors but does not save. Or I should say the saveMany call does not work, the saveField works and saves the ID number which I call from one of my other tables.

A bit of code I forget to add are the vars, which are just basic holders for the $this->data I am trying to save.

```
       $WorkHolder = $this->data['workdes'];
   $PriceHolder = $this->data['price'];
```

Please Help......

Glenn.

OK Here goes, I try and see if I can explain myself in more detail.

I am going to re-do so of my work to make it just plan easier for the UI apart form anything. To explain, I will now have a form which sets the invoice job, e.g jobnumber per user, user id, and other bits. This information will go into a table call invoicejoblist

The second table invoicedata holds just workdes and price along with invociejoblists_id (this links each row with the invoice job details).

But no matter what I do I can not get it to save into workdes and price. This is how my current test setup looks :

MY .cpt file:

```
$InvoiceMake = $this->Form->create('Invoice', array('url'=>'/InvoiceSet/', 'id' => 'InvoiceSet', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) );
$InvoiceMake .= "<div id=\"InvoiceDataInput\">Please Input Description<br />";  
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->textarea('Invoicedata.0.workdes');
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->textarea('Invoicedata.1.workdes');
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->textarea('Invoicedata.2.workdes');
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->textarea('Invoicedata.3.workdes');
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->textarea('Invoicedata.4.workdes');
    $InvoiceMake .= "</div>";
    $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->submit('Make Invoice', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'ButtonInvoice'));
 $InvoiceMake .= $this->Form->end();
echo $InvoiceMake;
```

My test function in controller:

```
function test() {
    debug($this->data); 
    $HoldeME = $this->data;
    $this->loadModel('Invoicedata');
            $this->Invoicedata->saveAll($HoldeME);
}
```

These return not errors but the workdes information submitted will not save. The only thing I put in my model was:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Invoicejoblists' => array(
        'className' => 'Invoicejoblists',
        'foreignKey' => 'invoicejoblists_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

I did have some checks to make sure the inputs where not empty but remove them to see if that was my problem, not sure it that was right or not.

Hope that is better explained, I have gone down to the right basic level to just test save any data set but it still will not let me, is that because I should have something in my model?

Any help most welcome

Glenn.

Comment: What you're doing seems incredibly overkill.  Maybe if you explain what you were actually trying to do, we can point you in a better direction.

Comment: why are you saving `'invoicejoblists_id'` twice in the same foreach iteration? Also note that `saveMany()` is using to save-many records at the same time in one Model. So normally you don't need to use foreach loop, because Cake will save all at once. Therefore if you want to get an answer you need to specify how does your Invoicedata model looks like. Because I can't figure out what do you want to save, like `''workdes''` and `'price'` are two columns in the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really have no clue what you're asking, but I'm giving it a blind-shot.

You should be able to save an item and as many sub/related items as you want in a single `saveAll()`.

Just make sure your form (or the data) is formatted correctly per the copious instructions found in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

As an example:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Invoice');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('Price.0.amount');
echo $this->Form->input('Price.1.amount');
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Then, when you do a `saveAll()` (or `saveMany()` - whatever), your Invoice will save as well as the two Prices (assuming `Invoice` is related to `Price`).

If you're trying to build the data manually, but don't know how it should be formatted, you can always create a form like above, submit it, and `debug()` the results to see how CakePHP would format it.

Hope that helps clarify for you.

Comment: Many thank! I have now paid around with my forms and it all seems to be saving good.